# How would I write a Python formula to sort through a database to move mismatched data over to clean a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pretty basic problem that I'm having trouble explaining verbally, otherwise, I would just use an older answer. Would definitely appreciate being pointed in the right direction

Here's an example of what I need assistance with:

|  | Project Name A | Population A | Project Name B | Population B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Zebra |  | Zebra | 124 |
| 1 | Horse |  | Parrot | 555 |
| 2 | Parrot |  |  |  |
| 3 | Pufferfish |  | Shark | 442 |
| 4 | Shark |  |  |  |
| 5 | Spider |  | Cow | 331 |
| 6 | Pig |  | Pig | 953 |
| 7 | Cow |  |  |  |

How would I be able to insert the population data from Population B into Population A, given that the column in the row next to it in Project Name B matches Project Name A?

Sorry I'm having trouble explaining this!

I tried using the loc function in Pandas inside a loop, but that did not work other than for the first row of data.

Comment: `df['Population A'] = df['Project Name A'].map(df.set_index('Project Name B')['Population B'])`

Comment: create two data frames from the databases then. Lets say PNA & PNB. Then do a merge in pandas "Merge = pd.merge(PNA, PNB, how = "inner", Left_on = "Project Name A", right_on = "Project Name B") . This should give you all the info you need to figure out what POP A should be. Could do something like if pop A is null then pop A = pop b or something of that nature.